# MAAS Node on Dell PowerEdge 710 & 2950 Hardware Crashes After Enlisting

Tags: maas

I am running an Ubuntu 15.04 MAAS Region Controller and trying to bring up my first node.  I have tried it with a Dell PowerEdge 2950 and  Dell PowerEdge R710 and both have the same problem.  They come up, boot from PXE, Get to maas-enlist login prompt, and then crash a Checking System V Runlevel Compatibility.  I do mean crash.  It immediately powers off the machine.  The Error codes from the dell hardware log I have seen are E1422 and E1715.  I am running the most recent BIOS, Firmware, and PERC Firmware.  I have also tried using Deployment images 14.04 and 15.04 with no change in behavior.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?  I would really like to use OpenStack for virtualization but this is definitely a show stopper.

Are there specific BIOS settings that I need to be running?

Thanks in advance!

Rusty

Comment: Nodes will power off automatically after enlistment and commissioning, so that part may be expected. Does the node show up in MAAS after enlistment? Have you set the node's power parameters and commissioned it?

Comment: The node shows up as new in the MAAS UI. When I watch the console of the node that is attempting to enlist i see it get to system V run level compatibility checking and then the machine immediately powers off. I'm expecting to see some sort of shutdown process that you would normally see at the console but I don't see that. Is that normal? I haven't actually attempted to proceed with commissioning thinking that there was some sort of hardware problem.  I have also attempted to power back on the node using the UI but have been unable to do so. The UI says that the node cannot be powered on.

Comment: Have configured the power settings to use Wake on LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned this effort and went with a Mirantis Distribution of OpenStack using Fuel for hardware provisioning.  Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get enlistment crashes recently
the MAAS server itself also run out of memory -
I attempted to let the maas-proxy run on another server . . since I was getting hdd full problems.  so I usually cleared the MAAS-proxy folder.  The out of disk space used to because loading more than two images / distributions.  14.04, 16.04 CENTOS 6, 7 - 6 replaced.  so I reduces using CENTOS 6 and 7 completely.

I only played with JUJU a while ago.

but now... recently - 2021 - all the MAAS commissioning are failing... and even the MAAS server itself (after increasing the available hard disk space

SSH session

```
login as: it
it@192.168.1.119's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-139-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

11 packages can be updated.
10 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


Last login: Tue Mar 23 20:12:17 2021 from 192.168.1.77
it@fz119:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              989952        0    989952   0% /dev
tmpfs             204084    21560    182524  11% /run
/dev/sda1       22654976 18070520   2826008  87% /
tmpfs            1020420       12   1020408   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1020420        0   1020420   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       22654976 18070520   2826008  87% /home
cgmfs                100        0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs             204084        0    204084   0% /run/user/1000

the version of MAAS is:
```

MAAS name: fz119 MAAS

MAAS version: 2.3.5 (6511-gf466fdb-0ubuntu1)

and commissioning / testing fail due to run out of memory.  Even the MAAS server run out of memory and I have increased it to 2GB in the virtual machine under Oracle Virtual Box